# How do I add a JSON Request using Retrofit?

Tags: java, json, api, retrofit, payload

I am trying to add a JSON Request via Retrofit because the server needs a JSON Request before I am able to pull out data.

This is the request that I want to add:

```
{"VALID_FROM":"2018-01-01","VALID_TO":"2019-03-15"}
```

I am receiving this message if there is no payload in Postman

> INCORRECT_PAYLOAD_DATA::::::Error while processing message payload
>   Element 'VALID_FROM' missing

This is my API Interface
SapRestApi.Java

```
public interface SapRestApi {       
    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @GET("/get_users")
    Call<UserList> getUserList();
}
```

And this is my User Class where the getters and setters are found
User.Java

```
public class User implements POJO {

    @SerializedName("USERNAME")
    private String USERNAME;
    @SerializedName("VALID_FROM")
    private String VALID_FROM;

    @SerializedName("VALID_TO")
    private String VALID_TO;

    public String getUserName() {
        return USERNAME;
    }

    public String getValidFrom() {
        return VALID_FROM;
    }

    public String getValidTo() {
        return VALID_TO;
    }

    public void setUserName(String USERNAME) {
        this.USERNAME = USERNAME;
    }
    public void setValidFrom(String VALID_FROM) {
        this.VALID_FROM = VALID_FROM;
    }

    public void setValidTo(String VALID_TO) {
        this.VALID_TO = VALID_TO;
    }
}
private String USERNAME;
```

This is where I call the getUserList()

```
public UserList getUserList() {     
    UserList userAccounts = null;

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
              .baseUrl(server)
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

              .client(httpClient
                      .addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor(userName, password))
                      .build())

              .build();

    SapRestApi userAPI = retrofit.create(SapRestApi.class);

    Call<UserList> callSync = userAPI.getUserList();



    try {




        Response<UserList> response = callSync.execute();

        System.out.println("Creating Response after Call Sync Execute Method ");
        System.out.println(response.toString());

        userAccounts = response.body();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return userAccounts;
}
```

I am getting an error 500 everytime when  there is no payload.
Thanks!